Fixed weights to 1 in confirmatory factor analysis - how significance (p) value is obtained?
I have a question somewhat related to this thread.
I now understand why the value of 1 should be fixed in the confirmatory analysis to one of paths, and I also understand that various tricks can be used to free this parameter. But I am interested in the question of how the statistical significance of fixed path to 1 is calculated with standarized solution.
Let's consider an example from here, I will use an example with Lavaan package in R.
library(lavaanPlot)
library(foreign) 
library(lavaan)

dat <- read.spss("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/SAQ.sav", to.data.frame=TRUE, use.value.labels = FALSE)

m1a  <- ' f  =~ q03 + q04 + q05'
onefac3items_a <- cfa(m1a, data=dat) 
summary(onefac3items_a) 

Here, as you can see in the summary, there is no statistical significance because the path f~q03 is fixed.
Latent Variables:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
  f =~                                                
    q03               1.000                           
    q04              -1.139    0.073  -15.652    0.000
    q05              -0.945    0.056  -16.840    0.000

Same for summary standarized:
summary(onefac3items_a,standardized=TRUE)
(...)

Latent Variables:
                   Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)   Std.lv  Std.all
  f =~                                                                  
    q03               1.000                               0.583    0.543
    q04              -1.139    0.073  -15.652    0.000   -0.665   -0.701
    q05              -0.945    0.056  -16.840    0.000   -0.551   -0.572

But, when use standardizedsolution function, i got p-value. How, why? How it's possible?
standardizedsolution(onefac3items_a)
  lhs op rhs est.std    se       z pvalue ci.lower ci.upper
1   f =~ q03   0.543 0.022  25.120      0    0.500    0.585
2   f =~ q04  -0.701 0.024 -29.710      0   -0.747   -0.655
3   f =~ q05  -0.572 0.022 -26.105      0   -0.615   -0.529

Same when i use plot i got significance stars.
lavaanPlot(model = onefac3items_a, coefs=T, covs=T, stars = c("covs","latent","regress"), stand=T)

I don't fully understand this mechanism. How does it happen that a path that is fixed and no coefficient is calculated for it suddenly has a value of statistical significance with the standardized solution? What method is used here? Is it that the program simply changes the place of the fixed path, e.g. for a moment we take the path f~q04 as fixed to 1 to calculate the coefficient for f~q03, or is the method completely different?
Bonus question: Can the same be achieved in AMOS? Cuz there are no significance levels with standarized solution, and with regresion weights there are no significances:


In the standardized solution, by definition, the variances of the factors are fixed ("standardized") to 1, which identifies the model. Therefore, the standardized loadings for all indicators can be estimated as free parameters with standard errors and test statistics.
Similarly, in an unstandardized solution, you may choose to fix the factor variance instead of one loading per factor for identification. Then, all loadings are estimated as free parameters with SEs and test statistics.
This principle applies to different (all?) SEM software programs including AMOS.

Thank you, now I understand how solution coefficients are calculated; however, for AMOS the output does not work this way, for fixed values ​​there have no significance values ​​calculated (I edited the question and pasted the output in question above).

Fixed coefficients never have a standard error or test statistic, regardless of whether they are standardized or unstandardized. Something that is not estimated does not have a standard error. You can see this also in the lavaan output where fixed loadings of 1 do not have a standard error. The key point is that certain coefficients (e.g., loadings) that are fixed in an unstandardized solution can be freely estimated in a standardized solution because in a standardized solution other parameters are fixed (i.e., variances), which makes fixing loadings unnecessary.
